Can we use "type of a thing","sort of a thing","kind of a thing" to express the meaning of "something like that"?
From twomadexplorers:

at 00:17:59
so, yeah, we don't really, uh do the Century egg, type of a thing. oh my God, look at these, guys. very interesting.

They also frequently use the words "kind of", "sort of", "type of" throughout the video.

at 00:07:52
these, here, walnuts, oh, lots of walnuts, preserved
stuff, fermented, looks like kimchi cabbage, kind of.

So can I sum it up like this? -"kind of", "sort of", "type of" is like "approximately ", "type of a thing","sort of a thing","kind of a thing" is similar to "something like that", the former indicates the adverb, the latter indicates the noun.

This sort of expression is very commonly used in informal speech.
In more careful speech it would be "We don't really do/make things like century eggs" and "It looks like a kind of kimchi cabbage". Adding sort of, kind of etc. at the end of a sentence to mean "...or something like that" is very informal.

So, at the end of a sentence, 'type of a thing' has the same meaning as 'sort of'?

Yes, it can do. As I understand it, making 'century eggs' is a very specific process, which is why I expressed it as '[some]thing like'.

@Mr.Wang Re "looks like kimchi cabbage, kind of," I think the best explanation is that "kind of" means "somewhat." The position at the end of the sentence is just coincidence here; they could just as well have said "looks kind of like kimchi cabbage."
